# nodejs ssl "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I've been given an SSL cert to use for signing client requests, as well as the relevant CA certs. I can verify it using openssl:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/foo/ca-combined.pem -servername foo.co.in -connect foo.co.in:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
... snip ...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

(I mashed the 2 CA certs into one file). But when I try to replicate it using node:

```
    var tls = require('tls');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var options = { 
        host: 'foo.co.in',
        servername: 'foo.co.in',
        port: 443,
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/foo.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/foo/cert.pem'),
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/foo/combined-ca.pem')]
    };  

    tls.connect(options, function(err) {
        done(err);
    });
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
  at Error (native)
  at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
  at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
  at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

I found an answer on here, suggesting that I need to put each CA cert in a separate file:

```
ca: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/foo/ca.pem'), fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/foo/root-ca.pem')]
```

but that still gave the same error. (I also tried reversing the order). I then tried putting the intermediate cert in with the client one, and just providing the root CA cert as ca (which seems to be what the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) suggest), same error. At this point I'm running out of ideas. The fact that openssl is happy suggests that I'm doing something wrong, any suggestions?

```
$ node --version
v6.10.1
```

(I realise I can set rejectUnauthorized to false, but I'd really rather not)

Comment: which backend server you are using? nginx, apache or something else?

Comment: that's out of my control. I gave them a CSR, and they generated a client cert for me, and gave me the CA certs

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968937/nodejs-request-post-not-working-for-https-website/46968984#46968984

Comment: turning off verification isn't a good solution, in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that I didn't need to supply the CA cert, as their CA was properly signed by a "known" authority. So I could just remove the ca field from my request.

Comment: Thanks! Same issue here, you saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 4):

I created a root-ca and a intermediate-ca (signed by root-ca) certificates, then I created a server and a client certificates signed by intermediate-ca. To test it I've been implementing a server and client https with nodejs so a set it up with the certs and a get the following error on my client:

```
problem with request: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

To solve it I need to put in my nodejs codes, at ca field, my root-ca and intermediate-ca certs. Like that:

```
key: fs.readFileSync('path/client.privkey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('path/client.cert.pem'),
ca: [ fs.readFileSync('path/intermed-ca.cert.pem'), fs.readFileSync('path/root-ca.cert.pem') ],
```

it works for me.

Comment: how i can to create client certificates ?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this generally for you system you have 2 different options:

The first is to export the variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=$PATH_TO_YOUR_CUSTOM_CA_FILE.pem` pointing to your custom CA_FILE

The second is to run node with the option `--use-openssl-ca` like:

```
node --use-openssl-ca main.js
```

This assumes that you already configured your ssl certificates with something like:

```
wget -qP /usr/local/share/ca-certificates http://your_local_cert/local_ca.pem\
    && update-ca-certificates
```

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5620

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue when I had to use my custom SSL certificate and pass it in the `ca` field of the `https.Agent`.

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions) clearly state that if you're overriding this field, you lose all certificates that were there by default:

> Mozilla's CAs are completely replaced when CAs are explicitly specified using this option.

So in my case, to resolve the issue I had to add default root certificates in the `ca` array like so:

```js
import https from "https";
import tls from "tls";
import { getMyCustomCert } from "@some-namespace/internal-cert";

new https.Agent({
    ca: [...tls.rootCertificates, getInternalCert()],
});
```