# NodeJS Request Post not working for HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

Im using NodeJS [Request - Simplified HTTP Client](https://github.com/request/request)

I seem to have problem working with HTTPS website, I am not getting result.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
    url: "",//your url
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },

    form: {
        myfield: "myfieldvalue"
    }
},function (response, err, body){
    console.log('Body:',JSON.parse(body));
}.bind(this));
```

Tested the API endpoint(which I cant share) on Postman, I just turn off SSL and it works, how do I do the same with request plugin?

Comment: What's the error...

Comment: Why loopbackjs tag?

Comment: There is not clearly shaped question and description, which is very important for the stackoverflow and the users which will check after for similar questions.

Comment: I think this one relates to origin when do server-call-server.

Comment: @vsenko I am using loopback with this one.

Comment: Q do you used this by docs?
https://github.com/request/request#tlsssl-protocol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add this lines:

```
    rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
    requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
    agent: false,//add when working with https sites
```

So your code would look like this:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
    url: "",//your url
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
    requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
    agent: false,//add when working with https sites
    form: {
        myfield: "myfieldvalue"
    }
},function (response, err, body){
    console.log('Body:',JSON.parse(body));
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what effect your suggested settings will cause? Options rejectUnauthorized and requestCert are not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @vsenko, essentially it just disable the ssl verification. which is a bit unsafe, if you dont trust the service you are connecting to.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be a good idea to clarify this in the answer, so that no one would ever use this approach in production.

Comment: @MarkRyanOrosa which one actually disables ssl verification? rejectUnauthorized? requestCert? agent? And what do the other two do?