# How to disable SSL verification nodejs Loopback Request Plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, loopbackjs

I am  new to both nodejs and loopback. and I want to make a post request. its working fine when connecting to our dev api. But when connecting to our production api, with https. its  seems to be getting blocked.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
    url: "",//removed for obvious reasons
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
        myfield: "myfieldvalue"
    }
},function (response, err, body){
    console.log('Body:',JSON.parse(body));
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Request Post not working for HTTPS website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968937/nodejs-request-post-not-working-for-https-website)

Comment: Really ? Even the snippet is the same !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
agent: false,//add when working with https sites
```

I got it working. found the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968937/nodejs-request-post-not-working-for-https-website?noredirect=1#comment80885426_46968937).