# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when sending https request Node.js and API

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, npm, https

I am developing a dashboard, I need to conect to a API and catch a Auth Token and afther that send info by using a HTTPS protocol. I use a Nodejs, and when I run my code I have the next error on the pm2 monit:

```html
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my.url.net/path
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'my.url.net/path'
}
```

Also here is my code where I made the request (Node.js):

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join('path','.env')});
const https     = require('https');
const database = require('./sql');
const fs         = require ('fs');

const user = process.env.USER;
const pwd  = PWD;
const host = 'https://my.url.net/extencio';
const host_1 = 'my.url.net/extention';

async function getLoginToken(pForce){

 if (login_token.Health && !pForce) { return login_token }

  //Creates the POST request
  const options = {
    protocol: 'https:',
    hostname: host_1,
    path: '/api/auth/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
  };

  //Body of the POST request, contains the user and password
  const post_data = JSON.stringify({username: user, password: pwd});
```

.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const req = new https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      response.on('data', function(chunk){
        const output = JSON.parse(chunk);

        if(output.token){
          login_token.Health = true;
          login_token.Token  = output.token;
          resolve(login_token)
        }

        else{
          login_token.Health = false;
          login_token.Token  = '';
          resolve(login_token);
        }
        
      });
    });
    req.write(post_data);
    req.end();
    
    req.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      login_token.Health = false;
      login_token.Token  = '';
      resolve(login_token)
    });
    
  });
}
```

Comment: But you're not making any HTTP request anywhere in this code

Comment: Sorry I mean HTTPS

Comment: But you're not making any HTTPS request anywhere in this code

Comment: I already did the question update

Answer (score 12):

Remove protocol, and use domain names only for the host. For instance:

Wrong:

```js
const host = 'https://my.url.net/extencio'
const path = '/api/auth/token'
```

Correct:

```js
const host = 'my.url.net'
const path = '/extencio/api/auth/token'
```

See [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback) for the `http.request` options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is trying to getaddrinfo of the full url, instead of just the hostname. I would put hostname in option as only "my.url.net" and update path with the rest of the url.

Comment: @Eric0607 do you mean you have tried 

"protocol":"https",

 "hostname": "my.url.net", 

"path": "extention/api/auth/token"

 (I'm not sure that path is ok, but it's based from your setup)

Please note also that protocol is not "https:"

Comment: Yes I mean the protocol https, "hostname" "my.url.net/extention", "path" "/api/auth/token" I need to use the https protocol because I have SSL certificates, also wen i made the change from http I get error that only https are spected:

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my.url.net/extention/api/auth/token
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
   errno: -3008,
   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
   hostname: 'my.url.net/extention/api/auth/token'
 }

Comment: So no, you didn't read. "hostname": "my.url.net" and not "my.url.net/extention". Furthermore, you didn't read well the protocol you have written in the question: it should be "https" and not "https:" because it doesn't have the colons.

Comment: I made the changes as it say and now I have HOST: my.url.net Path: /Ext/api/auth/token

but now I have this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810720/error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-node-js

Any idea. Thank alot for the help

Answer (score 0):

@Eric0607 the error stackoverflow.com/questions/65810720/… you've provided is not showing anymore, I might've been too late to reply.

but in case you got "***an invalid local cert SSL error***", here is a fix I found that works for it.
[disable SSL check in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968937/nodejs-request-post-not-working-for-https-website/46968984#46968984), not recommended but it would work temporarily, turn it on after you're done or it can be risky.